# Circuit Simulator in C input

Tags: c

I have to create a circuit based off the inputs of a text file i read. 
The first text file I use has the circuit description and then the next has the actual binary values of the circuit you end up creating.

```
 Example:
 INPUTVAR 3 A B C
 OUTPUTVAR 1 Q
 AND A B w
 AND A C x
 OR w x Q
```

the format of this example means that there are 3 input variables called A, B , C. There is also 1 output variable called Q. The And creates an expression called w= A.B. along with x=A.C. and the or is Q = w.x. My problem is that I do not know how to read in this input since it isnt the same format every time. The amount of variables after the INPUTVAR depends on what that first number says. I am confused on how I can interpret this in code, I know how to read in data that is formatted. Any hints or help provided will be appreciated.

I believe I need to use fgets() to do it line by line.

with help I have came up with the following code

```
 FILE *circuit;
 circuit = fopen(argv[1],"r");
 char line[50];
 char *str;
 while (fgets(line,sizeof(line),circuit) != NULL)
 {
 str = strtok(line," "); //space is DELIM
 printf("str is: %s\n",str);
 }
```

I am geting the following outputs from the text file that I included as an example: 
str is: INPUTVAR
str is: OUTPUTVAR
str is: AND
str is: AND
str is: OR

How do I go about getting the characters after the first word of each line?

Comment: Use `strtok()` on each line you have read, to break it into tokens, then you can follow different logic for each initial keyword. In the first two cases, the second item tells you how many more to expect.

Comment: okay that actually makes a lot of sense, i would use strtok in addition to using fgets() to read line by line  correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted your code [please pardon any gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
FILE *circuit;

circuit = fopen(argv[1], "r");
char line[50];
char *str;
char *cp;

while (1) {
    cp = fgets(line, sizeof(line), circuit);
    if (cp == NULL)
        break;

    cp = strchr(line,'\n');
    if (cp != NULL)
        *cp = 0;

    cp = line;
    while (1) {
        str = strtok(cp, " ");
        cp = NULL;

        if (str == NULL)
            break;

        printf("str is: %s\n", str);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Per your request, here is a more generalized solution that gets you closer.  This compiles but is untested.  But, it should give you the idea.

```
// circuit -- circuit simulator

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// command parsing control
// NOTE: this can be build up if desired
struct cmd {
    const char *cmd_str;                    // command string
    const char *(*cmd_parse)(struct cmd *); // command parse function
};

// forward declarations
const char *parse_inputvar(struct cmd *cmd);
const char *parse_outputvar(struct cmd *cmd);
const char *parse_and(struct cmd *cmd);
const char *parse_or(struct cmd *cmd);

// list of supported commands
struct cmd cmdlist[] = {
    { .cmd_str = "INPUTVAR", .cmd_parse = parse_inputvar },
    { .cmd_str = "OUTPUTVAR", .cmd_parse = parse_outputvar },
    { .cmd_str = "AND", .cmd_parse = parse_and },
    { .cmd_str = "OR", .cmd_parse = parse_or },
    { .cmd_str = NULL }
};

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    FILE *circuit;
    char line[5000];
    char *cp;
    struct cmd *cmd;
    const char *err;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    circuit = fopen(*argv, "r");

    while (1) {
        cp = fgets(line, sizeof(line), circuit);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        cp = strchr(line,'\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;

        cp = strtok(line," ");

        err = NULL;
        for (cmd = cmdlist;  cmd->cmd_str != NULL;  ++cmd) {
            if (strcmp(cp,cmd->cmd_str) == 0) {
                err = cmd->cmd_parse(cmd);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (cmd->cmd_str == NULL)
            printf("unknown command -- '%s'\n",cp);

        if (err != NULL)
            printf("error in %s command -- %s\n",cmd->cmd_str,err);
    }

    fclose(circuit);
}

const char *
parse_inputvar(struct cmd *cmd)
{
    char *cp;
    char *sym;
    int cnt;
    int idx;
    const char *err = NULL;

    do {
        // get the count string
        cp = strtok(NULL," ");
        if (cp == NULL) {
            err = "missing count";
            break;
        }

        // decode count string into number
        cnt = atoi(cp);
        if (cnt <= 0) {
            err = "bad count";
            break;
        }

        for (idx = 0;  idx < cnt;  ++idx) {
            sym = strtok(NULL," ");

            if (sym == NULL) {
                err = "missing symbol";
                break;
            }

            // NOTE: sym will be invalid after we return so we need to preserve
            // it now
            sym = strdup(sym);

            // do whatever ...
        }
    } while (0);

    return err;
}

const char *
parse_outputvar(struct cmd *cmd)
{
    const char *err = NULL;

    return err;
}

const char *
parse_and(struct cmd *cmd)
{
    const char *err = NULL;

    return err;
}

const char *
parse_or(struct cmd *cmd)
{
    const char *err = NULL;

    return err;
}
```

Comment: If to make it easier on me, I kind of want to read the first word and then want to from there have a series of if statements determining if it is either the inputvar or outputvar or any of the circuits, is there a way to just read the first word, then read the rest of that line after you decide what you should do with it?

Comment: As an aside, if you use `strtok()` you don't need to clutter the code by specifically removing the trailing `newline`. Just add it to the separator string, as `str = strtok(cp, " \r\n");`

Answer (score 0):

You can read the line of input, using fgets(), as a string and them do a split() function on it to parse it into numbers. The split creates an array of strings using spaces as delimiters. The first string will be INPUTVAR in string format, then you can do an atoi() on that to convert to a number.

Comment: @bkennedy: so you know how many arguments should follow on `INPUTVAR` and `OUTPUTVAR` lines.